# Magento 1 - get category ID from product ID

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value, magento-1.4

In magento how to get the category id of each product from its product ID.

```
   $items    = $request->getAllItems();
    $c           = count($items); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        if ($items[$i]->getProduct() instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {

            if ($items[$i]->getProduct()->getId()) {
               $this->_dhlAllowed    = false;
              }
        }
    }
```

Here `$items[$i]->getProduct()->getId()` returns product ID. I want its category ID.

Comment: $items[$i]->getProduct()->getCategoryIds() ; This returns category ID in one server but in not another server.  Any idea?

Comment: Did you tried reindexing the flat category tables on the server? This kind of strange things are commonly associated with an outdated (or corrupted) index.

Answer (score 6):

```
public function getProductCategory() {
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product->getId()) {
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if (is_array($categoryIds) and count($categoryIds) >= 1) {
            return Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds[0]);
        };
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `count($categoryIds)` should be `>= 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryId();
```

this way, category id of a current product can be get.

Answer (score 2):

suppose if you want all category ids from current product id you can get from

```
Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();
```

it may help you