# MAGENTO - get category name in product.info.extrahint reference page

Tags: magento, categories, product

I was created a product.info.extrahint page.
Here is my frontend layout :

```
    <catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="product.info.extrahint">
         <block type="***_***/product" name="***_product" template="***/***/product.phtml" />
       </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

My product.php extended from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

How to get category name in product.php?

Comment: I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413565/magento-category-id-from-product-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load product model, then get categories list and echo out the ones you want?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($categories as $catid) {
    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)->getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks about your answer.. but it's not work. when I var_dump ($categories);, i get empty array array(0) { }

Comment: I've tested successfully in 1.7.0.2 - is your product model loading correctly?